# Magento Stuck at running command

Tags: command-line, setup-di-compile, compiler, command

[image]

My Magento command for compile is stuck What should I do and what is the problem??

Comment: you change the many codes and after run this command.So this command is stuck but you get long time succes

Comment: you wait this success command

Comment: You need to give more detail for us to help you fix this. Is this a new install? What version of Magento 2? Try removing recently added modules and try again. 
Then run these commands 
php bin/magento module:enable --all
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Do your logs say anything?
var/log/exception.log
var/log/system.log
web server logs?

Answer (score 0):

you can enable developer mode and check

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```